# Tensorflow: sum/product an array to specific elements in a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi i have an array of float [time,position] coordinates in a sparse format, eg

```
times = [0.1, 0.1, 1.5, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9]
posit = [2.1, 3.5, 0.4, 1.3, 2.7, 3.5]
```

and an array of velocities, eg

```
vel = [0.5,0.7,1.0]
```

I have to multiply each positions at the `i`-th time with the `i`-th element of `vel`.

In numpy is quite simple with a for:

```
import numpy

times = numpy.array([0.1, 0.1, 1.5, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9])
posit = numpy.array([2.1, 3.5, 0.4, 1.3, 2.7, 3.5])

vel = numpy.array([0.5,0.7,1.0])

uniqueTimes = numpy.unique(times, return_index=True)
uniqueIndices = uniqueTimes[1]
uniqueTimes = uniqueTimes[0]

numIndices = numpy.size(uniqueTimes)-1
iterator = numpy.arange(numIndices)+1
for i in iterator:
    posit[uniqueIndices[i-1]:uniqueIndices[i]] = posit[uniqueIndices[i-1]:uniqueIndices[i]]*vel[i-1]
```

In tensorflow i can gather every information i need with

```
import tensorflow as tf

times = tf.constant([0.1, 0.1, 1.5, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9])
posit = tf.constant([2.1, 3.5, 0.4, 1.3, 2.7, 3.5])

vel = tf.constant([0.5,0.7,1.0])   

uniqueTimes, uniqueIndices, counts = tf.unique_with_counts(times)
uniqueIndices = tf.cumsum(tf.pad(tf.unique_with_counts(uniqueIndices)[2],[[1,0]]))[:-1]
```

but i can't figure how to do the product. With `int` elements i could use sparse to dense tensors and use `tf.matmul`, but with `float` i can't.
Moreover, looping is difficult, since `map_fn` and `while_loop` require same size of each 'row', but i have different number of positions at each times. For the same reason i can't work separately each time and update the final `positions` tensor with `tf.concat`. Any help? Maybe with `scatter_update` or Variable assignment?

---

Following answer from vijai m, i have differences up to 1.5% between numpy and tensorflow code. You can check it using these data

```
times [0.1,  0.1, 0.2, 0.2]
posit [58.98962402,  58.9921875, 60.00390625, 60.00878906]
vel [0.99705114,0.99974157]
```

They return

```
np: [ 58.81567188  58.8182278   60.00390625  60.00878906]
tf: [ 58.81567001  58.81822586  59.98839951  59.9932785 ]
differences: [  1.86388465e-06   1.93737304e-06   1.55067444e-02   1.55105566e-02]
```

Comment: Can you fix the numpy code and also print the output you want.

Comment: I'm so sorry, copy-paste mistake :( edited

Comment: Manually calculating, the last value of the result is obtained by 60.00878906*0.99974157 = 59.9932785?

Comment: Yes, i'm noticing now that when `vel` approaches to `1` numpy returns same value of `posit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numpy code doesn't work. I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
uniqueTimes, uniqueIndices, counts = tf.unique_with_counts(times)
out = tf.gather_nd(vel,uniqueIndices[:,None])*posit
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer works, but using my data, even in float64, it returns me values with differences up to 1.5% with respect to numpy code, that for my purposes is quite much. I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: The above numpy code is giving me wrong values compared to manual calculation, can you post the numpy example which gives the difference of 1.5%?.

Comment: Are you sure? I just checked and numpy code gives to me exactly same values as manual calculation: `[ 1.05  1.75  0.28  1.3   2.7   3.5 ]`, do you have same values?

Comment: Anyway, i edited question with data you can use to check my results. Thank you again